# Interval between httpwebequest in TPL

Tags: c#, multithreading, httpwebrequest, task-parallel-library

I am using `Parallel.ForEach`. In the parallel loop I have 2 `HttpWebRequest` instances. How can I set the interval between these 2 requests.

As this is similar to multithreading, I've tried a 1 second delay using `Thread.Sleep(1000)`, but this is not working. Any other suggestion?

Comment: 2 synchronous web requests on each thread?

Comment: You need to add more info. It doesn't make a lot of sense to do something in parallel but constrain it to run in sequence with a specified time in between.

Comment: Actually it is the terms and conditions of the website to wait one sec before sending another request. So do you think I dont need parallel.foreach?

Comment: Do you want to have these requests repeat at certain intervals?

Comment: Not repeat, just executing after a sec

Comment: Well, no, you don't *want* them to run in parallel if you have to wait a second between them. Just run one, wait a second, and run the other.

Comment: @ Jim Mischel: please put it as an answer so I can mark it.